# Post method throws an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-http, misspelling

I am trying to do a test app based on app from tutorial  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 . It works fine but I have with post method.

index.html

```
...
<div class="control_panel" ng-controller="phonecatControllers">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="chiliSpicy()">Chili!</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendData()">send!</button>
</div>
...
```

controllers.js

```
'use strict';

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function ($scope, $http, $log) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/myresource/posts').
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.posts = data;
            });

        $scope.data = "hello world";

        $scope.chiliSpicy = function () {
            $log.info('chili function');
        };

        $scope.sendData = function () {
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/myresource/',  {'data' : $scope.data} )               
                .succes(function (data, status, headers, config) {  // !!! here is line 39
                    $log.info('sent');
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.error('not sent')
                });
        };
    }]);
```

Get method works ok (showed html code does not contain its usage), also chiliSpicy function works. But sendData function throws error (where success function is)

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at l.$scope.sendData (http://localhost:8080/webapp/controllers.js:39:18)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:198:424
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:798:21
    at l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:84)
    at l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:310)
    at l.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1478:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:797:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:32:363)
```

Actually, the server receives data, but success function do not pass. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: because your success function has only one argument? Also misspelled succes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misspelled `success`, written as `succes`.

Answer (score 1):

There is typo. It should be success instead of 'succes'

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function ($scope, $http, $log) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/myresource/posts').
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.posts = data;
            });

        $scope.data = "hello world";

        $scope.chiliSpicy = function () {
            $log.info('chili function');
        };

        $scope.sendData = function () {
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/myresource/',  {'data' : $scope.data} )               
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  // !!! here is line 39
                    $log.info('sent');
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.error('not sent')
                });
        };
    }]);
```